# How is Faraday's Law true if we cannot define a potential energy corresponding to a non conservative field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Faradays Law states that,
$$ EMF = -\frac{d\phi}{dt} $$
where the EMF is the due to the induced E-field. But, this induced E-field is non conservative. We cannot define a potential energy corresponding to a non conservative field. How then, can we define potential and hence EMF?

Comment: What do you think $\phi$ is in your equation?

Comment: The magnetic flux?

Comment: Potential is a change in work (per unit charge). \int E \cdot dl (left side of Faraday's law) is the work done, so this is your potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EMF is simply the electric field integrated around the loop:

$$ \operatorname{EMF}=-\oint\vec E\cdot d\vec l $$

The electric field can be written in two parts, in terms of the scalar potential $V$ and the vector potential $\vec A$.

$$ \vec E=-\nabla V-{\partial\vec A\over\partial t} $$

If you plug this into the integral above, it's easy to show that the first part vanishes. That is, the EMF has units of voltage, but it has nothing to do with the conservative scalar potential $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Faraday's law states $$\varepsilon=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$ where $\Phi$ is called $\textbf{magnetic flux}$ (is not a potential). It is defined by a flux integral $$\Phi=\int_{\Sigma} \,\textbf{B} \bullet\textbf{da} $$
Using the definition of electromotive force we obtain the "integral form" of Faraday's law $$\oint_{\gamma}\, \textbf{E}\bullet\textbf{dl}=\int_{\Sigma} \,\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\textbf{B} \bullet\textbf{da} $$ And using Stokes' Theorem we obtain the "differential form" $$\nabla\times\textbf{E}=-\frac{\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Maybe worth mentioned that $\varepsilon$ is not a vector field?

Comment: i meant that the induced electric field, is non conservative, how can we define a potential or EMF onding to a non conservative field?

Comment: I'm aware that $ \phi $ is the magnetic flux, not a potential.

Comment: Since $\nabla\cdot\textbf{B}=0$ we can always write $\textbf{B}=\nabla\times\textbf{A}$, where $\textbf{A}$ is called "the vector potential". Putting this in Faraday's law we can write $\textbf{E}=-\nabla V-\frac{\partial\textbf{A}}{\partial t}$ as you can check. Also you can check chapter 10 of Griffiths for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The $EM F$ is a *potential difference*, therefore, it remains the same for any gauge.

$$EM F=V_1-V_2=(V_1+k)-(V_2+k)$$

for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Doesn't the question ask why the we can define a $EM F$ when we can't define a potential?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with gauges. A non-conservative field can't have a potential written for it, regardless of gauge.